# What are the possible causes of a stack overflow?

Tags: stack-overflow, stack

What are the possible causes of a stack overflow?

Comment: If you have a specific problem you might want to *tell us what it is*

Comment: The wikipedia article on "stack overflow" isn't clear enough?

Comment: People need their technical questions answered!  Hence the need for Stack Overflow... ;)

Answer (score 6):

- Excessive recursion
- Creating a large
  variable on the stack instead of the
  heap

Answer (score 5):

Other question-and-answer web sites aren't very good.  That's what causes stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Other question-and-answer-sites must always be referred to with-an-evil-hyphen-of-course